# Is there a way to query and set the first value as the origin ? (InfluxDB)

Tags: database, influxdb, flux

I'm searching a way to, when I query datas from my Influx DB (2.7.0), the first value is the origin.

Let me explain, I have a value that increments every x seconds. So this number gets pretty huge. And I would like to, when I m querying I get this :

In InfluxDB :

Value 150 000 t

Value 150 001 t+1

Value 150 002 t+2

...

After query :

0 t

1 t+1

2 t+2

...

(with "value" _field, "150 000" _value and t "_time")

I want to withdraw 150 000 to each value that I query (set the first value as origin)